# Use custom where clause on EF's Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm running into the following problem:

In this project it is mandatory that the registries should not be physically (from the database) deleted, so I create a bool property named `deleted` on each class that represents a table on the database.

In a delete case, the property will become true and need to be only accessible, in any case, by SQL Queries inside the Database.

I made the repositories and etc to always return the `IQueryables` with a `query.where(x => !x.Deleted)`, but how can I do this on the `Collections` that are 'lazy loaded' by EF?

For example, when I get a Person and it has a `ICollection`, it always comes populated with all objects linked to that `Person`, I always have to filter the deleted ones manually.

Is there a way to tell EF that in every Lazy Loading it should use a custom where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter out the deleted entities while mapping the `DbSet` itself by overriding `OnModelCreating`.

Example:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false))
            .Ignore(m => m.IsDeleted);
    }
}
```

This will set a default value of `false` for the `IsDeleted` property and filters out records where `IsDeleted` is true.

More info: https://putshello.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/entity-framework-soft-deletes-are-easy/

Comment: Holy Moly, that works! Probably I was searching for the wrong keywords, I never though of 'soft delete' term.